# Why Yeoman can't perform async callback after exec method?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, bower, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm triyng to perform a [async callback](http://yeoman.github.io/generator/RunContext.html) in my action after the [bowerInstall](http://yeoman.github.io/generator/install.html) method is completed (the problem is the same with others methods using exec commands). I need this because without it the next action will be triggered before the method is completed.

```
     _-----_
    |       |    .--------------------------.
    |--(o)--|    |   Yeoman is frustrated   |
   `---------´   |     Help him please!     |
    ( _´U`_ )    '--------------------------'
    /___A___\
     |  ~  |
   __'.___.'__
 ´   `  |° ´ Y `
```

The issue is Yeoman doesn't support async callback situated in method callback.

```
default: {
  installPackage: function () {
    done = this.async();
    this.bowerInstall(this.packageName, function () {
      done();
    });
  },
  nextAction: function () {
    // Do stuff after installPackage is completed.
  }
}
```

In this case, the bowerInstall method is never triggered and the run loop breaks.

**[EDIT] SOLUTION**

Like Simon Boudrias said, I can't use an async callback in the install context. I have to put the tasks I want to run after the install in the end context.

```
install: {
  installPackage: function () {
    this.bowerInstall(this.packageName);
  }
},
end: {
  nextAction: function () {
    // Do stuff after installPackage is completed.
  }
}
```

Comment: not helpful for this specifically, but you don't need to wrap done in a function to then envoke it. just pass it uninvoked. e.g. `this.bowerInstall(this.packageName, done)`

Comment: @Patrick yes it's true but i did other things in the method callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeoman installation methods are automatically scheduled during the `install` task loop.

By using `this.async()` here, you're deadlocking the process.

This change was documented on [the v0.18.0 release](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/releases/tag/v0.18.0). Might be worth it to detail that behavior more explicitly on the install methods documentation -> https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman.io/blob/master/app/authoring/dependencies.md

Comment: Thanks for your attention Simon. I take this opportunity to thank you for all the great tools that you created for the community. I edit my question with your solution.